# Função Primeiro elemento Pilha

Tags: c

Como faço uma função que retorna o **primeiro elemento inserido** de uma *pilha*?

#### Por exemplo:

eu adiciono valores inteiros na minha pilha vetor de tamanho 5.

```
3
4
5
6
7
```

Tem que retornar o primeiro elemento inserido na pilha, neste caso o 3.

Eu fiz essa aqui:

```
float retornatopo ( struct Pilha *p ){

if(p->topo < 10)
return p->pElem [p->topo - 1];
else
    return -1;
```

}

Mas essa retorno o topo da pilha, preciso do primeiro elemento inserido (**FIFO**).

Comment: *first in last out - FIFO* e *last in first out - LIFO*

Comment: Então eu não pretendo retirar o elemento, apenas imprimir na tela o primeiro elemento inserido.

Comment: O primeiro elemento não seria o pElem[0]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode simplesmente fazer uma função que retorna o primeiro elemento desta maneira:

```
float primeiroElemento ( struct Pilha *p ) {
    if( p->topo > 0 )
        return p->Elem[0];

    return -1;
}
```

A função acima verifica se há elementos na pilha, se houver retorna o primeiro. Senão retorna -1;

Você pode fazer desta forma tranquilamente. Mas caso seu objetivo seja **retirar** o primeiro elemento e **manter o resto dos elementos na mesma ordem**, eu **desaconselho** o uso da função que citei. Aliás, ela apenas **retorna o valor** que está na posição 0 da pilha. Caso queira retirar o elemento essa função **não serve.**

Comment: Era isso deu certinho, até que emfim alguém entendeu de primeira. Parabéns. Sempre faço perguntas aqui fique de olho.